# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/gl.h': No such file or directory on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

I have tried several example and several solutions but it still doesn't solve the problem. I am unable to build any openGL projects. I think it relates to windows 10. i have installed the Windows 10 SDK and set the additional directories to a new folder for Glut but glut.h and freeglut.h runs perfectly. However the GL.h is undetectable.
p/s: it may help if you guys can tell me where I could find the gl.h directory

Comment: It is missing from the SDK version you use, 8.0.  But is back in [version 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx).  Changing the toolset to v110_xp is another way.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It may be very helpful if I can post a picture here but I can't do to achievement something. I just installed the version 8.1 without any more modifications.